# Is there any way to make text responsive to color?

Tags: html, css

This might be a dumb question, but I have a background that has high contrasting colors and I want my `<ul>`'s `<li>`s to change color depending on what the background color is for *each individual* `<li>`. I really don't want to bloat my CSS by adding the `color` property to each one. Please can someone tell me if there is any way to do this.

I'm working an a CodePen project. It's a personal portfolio page. Just for reference I'll share it with you but it's not finished yet. I want the list under *My Skills* to be "color responsive" (if that even exists) so that the items at the bottom are easier to read.

[Here is the pen.](https://codepen.io/RyanED/full/PjBdWd/)

Much appreciated!

Comment: Not 100% but "mix-blend-mode" might help: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/

Comment: if you want to highlight your skills with these kind of background, it would be better to add a overlay background which will be semi transparent and text will appear good

Comment: You can also try to use multiple text-shadow to simulate a stroke : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwGPvQ  test example : `text-shadow:0 0 1px black ,0 0 1px black ,0 0 1px black ,0 0 2px;`

Comment: @GCyrillus a single text-shadow worked pretty well. thanks! but i like the mix-blend-mode trick. its super cool

Comment: @caramba thanks. ive never heard of mixed-blend-mode before but i like it!

Answer (score 2):

Just using `CSS`, you can use `mix-blend-mode` to `ul`.

Chcek with `css` to `ul` element as `mix-blend-mode: difference;`

Comment: This is super cool. First time hearing about `mixed-blend-mode`. I'm stuck between `difference` and `exclusion`. I don't know which one works better

Comment: `Difference`: Subtracts the darker of the two constituent colors from the lighter color. Painting with white inverts the backdrop color; painting with black produces no change.

`Exclusion` : Produces an effect similar to that of the Difference mode but lower in contrast. Painting with white inverts the backdrop color; painting with black produces no change.

Answer (score 0):

The `mix-blend-mode` property defines how an element’s content should blend with its background. This means that any images or text, borders or headings will be influenced by this property.

See [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/). Ref: [Pen](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/ZYdjmZ)

```js
var modeList = [
  "normal",
  "multiply",
  "screen",
  "overlay",
  "darken",
  "lighten",
  "color-dodge",
  "color-burn",
  "hard-light",
  "soft-light",
  "difference",
  "exclusion",
  "hue",
  "saturation",
  "color",
  "luminosity"
],
  elem = document.querySelector(".box"),
  propertyName = "mix-blend-mode",
  modeElem = document.querySelector(".mode-name"),
  duration = 2500;

var i = 0;
var activate = setInterval(function() {
  if (i == modeList.length) i = 0;
  var mode = modeList[i];
  elem.style.mixBlendMode = mode;
  modeElem.innerText = mode;
  i++;
}, duration);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.wrapper {
 background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14179/washington.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 font-family: "Nocturno Display Medium 4", Georgia;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.box {
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 font-size: 8vw;
 border-top: 10px solid #BF0A30;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #BF0A30;
 line-height: 1;
 background-color: #002B65;
 color: white;
 background-size: cover;
 mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
 height: 400px;
 height: 50vh;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.box p {
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 word-spacing: 5px;
 margin: 0;
}

.mode-name-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 12vh;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 color: #002B65;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 17px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 135px;
 height: 135px;
 border: 5px solid white;
 background-color: #ddd;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.mode-name-wrapper:before {
 content: "★";
 display: block;
 line-height: 1;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: -20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 color: #ef0d3c;
 animation: spin 2.5s ease;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 transform-origin: center center;
}

.mode-name {
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 animation: nudge 2.5s ease;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }

 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes nudge {
 0% {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
 }

 80% {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
 }

 90% {
  transform: translate(-10px, 0);
 }

 93% {
  transform: translate(12px, 0);
 }

 95% {
  transform: translate(-8px, 0);
 }

 100% {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.typonine.com/WF-003562-001299.css" type="text/css" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Washington D.C.</p>
  </div>
  <small class="mode-name-wrapper">
    <span class="mode-name">hard-light</span>
   </small>
</div>
```